# How do I restart a hung loginwindow?

Tags: vnc, osx-mavericks, finder

I'm running OS X as a server (10.9.4) and the following things keep happening over and over.  Things will run smoothly for a while and then the GUI will simply crap out.  I'm not sure if it is caused by me logging in via VNC or if it is already like that by the time I do but that it when I notice it (it is headless).  FTP, SMB, SSH, and *everything* else keeps running normally except that loginwindow is pegged at 100% CPU usage.  It won't respond to any `kill` commands besides `-9` but doing that simply causes it to fall into an eternal void of darkness which only a reboot can remember (and only then for a few weeks).  I can find no way to launch loginwindow manually.  I've tried running through the plists that launch it but it simply refuses.

I don't like rebooting the server because it needs to be planned in advance so clients can continue connecting to it, so I would appreciate any suggestions as to how to resolve this renegade loginwindow without a reboot.

Comment: I think run level or set run level 3 followed by 5 or 9 should reset the you. (From a terminal ) you can also try to access alternative terminals by pressing f1 - f9.

Comment: @Jay I don't think OS X has a concept of run levels, does it?

Comment: It seems it might based on information I found here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/546707?start=0&tstart=0 and here http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1683640 after all its basically a Unix variant.

Comment: @Jay Yes, but BSD doesn't use that concept as others do (as indicated in your first link) and the second link says "This is meaningless on Mac OS X."

Comment: Well I guess that removes that possibility then.